# forbid javascript in html file

Tags: javascript, html

Following problem:
I've given a file with HTML inside but also maybe some script code.

Now I want to edit the file so that no script gets executed when opening the file with a browser.

My question is: What do I have to do?
Which possibilities are there to place a script inside HTML to let it get executed? I know there is the script tag, you could also do it with an iframe but what else is possible?

I definitely want to prevent any kind of script execution. How can I achieve this?

Comment: why dont you comment all the scripts with   // or  /*  */ or <!--   -->

Comment: Disable scripts at browser level (there is an option)

Comment: @ARUN, Because I don't know if there are more possibilities to let scripts get executed

Comment: Apart from script tags, you have to look out for event handler attributes such as onload and style declarations; also external CSS files

Comment: @RegisPortalez Portalez that's not an option for me, I have to edit the file

Comment: can you show the a part of the file, and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @ARUN, there is no specific file. It has to work every time for every possible file

Comment: You mean that you have an html file which you want to edit to remove all javascript content?

Comment: Or you are writing a tool to remove javascript?

Comment: @RegisPortalez, exactly, it should work automatically in the end

Comment: Just curious, why'd you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at an established, well tested HTML filter library such as http://htmlpurifier.org/ which uses a whitelist to filter possibly malicious code. Don't rely on the filtered HTML documents being secure from any javascript though, time and time again browsers are updated and new ways to sneak in javascript are discovered.